# Magento 2 : How to bulk update product atributes?

Tags: magento2, product, product-attribute

I am trying to update bulk product attributes
where i need to update attribute to "allow in search".

Any way to achieve it ?

Comment: Any way to achieve it ?

Comment: Any way to achieve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to your magento2 database find your attribute/s in the `eav_attribute` table and note the `attribute_id` number/s

In the `catalog_eav_attribute` table change the `is_searchable` value from 0 to 1 for each attribute to enable "*Use in Search*"

For example for attribute_id #256:

```
UPDATE `catalog_eav_attribute` SET `is_searchable` = '1' WHERE `catalog_eav_attribute`.`attribute_id` = 256;
```

Reindex and clear caches. For this change to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

In this class, you can find Magento sample for update attribute
`Model/ResourceModel/Product/Action.php`
`updateAttributes` method